# How to set C++ standard version when build with Bazel?

Tags: c++, bazel

I'm kinda new to C++. I know how to set C++ version with CMake, but don't know how to set C++ version in Bazel.

Maybe set with the `copts` parameter in `cc_libary` but I have to set this in every `cc_libary`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

To set the standard using the default C++ toolchain in Bazel you can set environment variable `BAZEL_CXXOPTS`, e.g. `BAZEL_CXXOPTS="-std=c++14"`. You can also set it from the command line or from `.bazelrc` using `--repo_env=BAZEL_CXXOPTS`. `:` is the flag separator.

Alternatively you can pass `--cxxopt` to Bazel, or put it into `.bazelrc`, e.g.  `--cxxopt='-std=c++11'`.

The robust solution to specifying C++ toolchain in Bazel is to use the `CcToolchainConfigInfo`. See the documentation at https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html and https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cc-toolchain-config-reference.html.

Comment: Kind of outrageous that a tool that was created to "easily" build C++ projects doesn't even support the most obvious C++ compiler option.  We can't be incorporating a whole new framework into our system for every tiny thing we want to do.  Is there really no way to specify in the BUILD file?

Comment: Your CROSSTOOL link is now broken, and if I'm reading [this](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/0.27.0/skylark/backward-compatibility.html#disallow-using-crosstool-to-select-the-cc_toolchain-label) correctly the CROSSTOOL file is now discouraged. I can't make heads or tails of the [toolchain](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/tutorial/cc-toolchain-config.html) page, but at least `--cxxopt=...` seems to work.

Comment: it is brittle to use --cxxopt to select a C++ standard if you are building in different platforms. for example --cxxopt=''-std=c++11" will work in linux gcc, but fails when using bazel for windows (which uses MSVC and requires --cxxopt="-std:c++11"

Comment: I found that adding a .bazelrc file with the contents `build --cxxopt='-std=c++17'` in the same directory as the WORKSPACE file did the trick. I don't think it is reasonable to put a config like this in the BUILD file because it could lead to mixing C++ standards across BUILD files. Tying it to the workspace makes more sense, as there can be only one workspace (and hence one C++ standard) in which you are building at a time.

Answer (score 9):

Add this to your `.bazelrc` next to your `WORKSPACE`:

```
build --action_env=BAZEL_CXXOPTS="-std=c++20"
```

If you want to set multiple options, separate them with a colon:

```
build --action_env=BAZEL_CXXOPTS="-std=c++20:-Werror"
```

It is kind of a workaround as bazel sets an environment variable which bazel then uses. But it works.

---

BTW: `build --cxxopt=-std=c++20` in the `.bazelrc` did not work form me.

Comment: Separating multiple options with colons did not work for me; I had to put multiple `build --cxxopt='…'` lines in `.bazelrc` (which should be next to `WORKSPACE`).

Comment: @Thomas I have the same problem. ubuntu 18.04 and bazel version is 6.0.0. But when I try it on mac (bazel version : 6.0.0) it's OK. What's yours?

Comment: @DanielLee I am not quite sure. I guess it was either Ubuntu 20.04 back then - I upgraded since then.

Answer (score 8):

`bazel build --cxxopt='-std=c++11' main:hello-world` This would work, but I wonder if there's way to set this `cxxopt` globally, like `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.

Comment: There is also BAZEL_CXXOPTS (and BAZEL_LINKOPTS) environment variable that you can set (https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/tools/cpp/unix_cc_configure.bzl#L364). Flag separator is colon.

Comment: Yes, this can be set globally by adding a line like `build --cxxopt='-std=c++17'` to a .bazelrc file in the same directory as your WORKSPACE file.

Comment: `build --cxxopt='-std=c++17'` did not work for me, but  `build --action_env=BAZEL_CXXOPTS="-std=c++17"` did.