# How to specify c++17 for visual studio in bazel?

Tags: visual-studio, bazel

I'm trying to compile a target with c++17 with bazel and visual studio 2019 on Windows 10.

I tried having `--cxxopt='-std=c++17'` inside `.bazelrc` in the same directory of my workspace, but this didn't work.

For instance, I got the error

```
C:\Users\marki\plasty>bazel build --verbose_failures labeling:semantic_seg
INFO: Analyzed target //labeling:semantic_seg (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
ERROR: C:/users/marki/plasty/labeling/BUILD:1:1: C++ compilation of rule '//labeling:semantic_seg' failed (Exit 2)
class template optional is only available with C++17 or later.
...
labeling/semantic_seg.cpp(183): error C2429: language feature 'structured bindings' requires compiler flag '/std:c++17'
Target //labeling:semantic_seg failed to build
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.184s, Critical Path: 0.84s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

I also tried `--cxxopt='/std:c++17'` with similar results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the option in *cc_binary* instead. For example:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "hello-main",
    srcs = ["hello-main.cpp"],
    deps = [":hellolib"],
    copts = ["/std:c++17"],
)
```

This will pass the option to the compiler *cl.exe*.

**UPDATE**

If you want to build with option in bazelrc, there is already an answer for that in:
[How to set C++ standard version when build with Bazel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260242/how-to-set-c-standard-version-when-build-with-bazel)
except that it is using c++11, so for c++17, add these in *.bazelrc*

```
build:c++17 --cxxopt=-std=c++1z
build:c++17 --cxxopt=-stdlib=libc++
build:c++1z --cxxopt=-std=c++1z
build:c++1z --cxxopt=-stdlib=libc++
```

Comment: This worked. But I like how on linux you only have to specify the flag once in the .bazelrc. Is there a similar feature for bazel on Windows?

Comment: Update the answer for using option with bazelrc

Comment: I have some trouble when set   `copts = ["/std:c++17"]`, I change to `copts = ["-std=c++11"],`